# how to check response type aiohttp asyncio python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, semaphore, aiohttp

I have the following method:

```py
    async def make_request(self, url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with self.limit, session.get(url=url) as response:
                resp = await response.read()
                await asyncio.sleep(self.rate)
                return resp
```

How to check if `resp` contains `json`? so that I could format in `json` e.g. `json.dumps(resp)` perhaps? and if the resp type is `html` then i will have to traverse the html tree to extract the `resp value`

I have tried:

```py
    async def make_request(self, url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with self.limit, session.get(url=url) as response:
                resp = await response.json()
                await asyncio.sleep(self.rate)
                return resp
```

But it errors out if the `resp` contains `html`

Comment: Maybe check for a content type header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above checking the `Content-Type` header should be the first step; however if for any reason that header is missing or is incorrect you can always use:

```
text = await response.text()
try:
    data = json.loads(text)
except ValueError as exc:
    print("cannot parse JSON: %s" % exc)
    # use text value
```